# Print stylesheet loaded from @import not working?

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-8

I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <span class="print">Print only</span> - <span class="noprint">Display Only</span>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```
@import url("screen.css") screen;
@import url("print.css") print;
```

**screen.css**

```
.print
{
    display:none;
}
```

**print.css**

```
.noprint
{
    display: none;
}

span.print
{
    display: inline !important;
}

div.print
{
    display: block !important;
}
```

When I view the page in the browser then as expected the "Display Only" span displays and the "Print Only" one doesn't.

However, when I go to print preview, or print the page, it doesn't appear to be using print.css?

I'm using IE8, which I thought supported @import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently IE doesn't support the "print" on the end of the @import line.
Use this instead:

```
@import url("screen.css");
@import url("print.css");
```

then add the "@media" rule into the stylesheet itself.

```
@media print
{

    .noprint
    {
        display: none !important;
    }

    span.print
    {
        display: inline !important;
    }

    div.print
    {
        display: block !important;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks man!  I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why IE wasn't displaying my print styles.